# Crear un código con instrucciones de máquina

Tags: array, algoritmos, ensamblador

Tengo el siguiente problema y no sé por dónde y cómo partir. Lo peor de todo es que me cuesta programar con instrucciones de máquina:

Se tiene un arreglo **A = [a1; a2; ... ; an]** de n enteros positivos con n un entero par.

Necesito implementar un código en IASSIM (simulador de arquitectura von neumann) que a partir de un arreglo A, calcule un arreglo B definido como 
               **B={|log2 a1|,|log2 a2|,...,|log2 an|}**
donde | | es la función piso que redondea al entero menor más cercano.
Se me recomienda implementar primero el |log2 x| y después ver una forma de recorrer un arreglo.

Anexo un link con la página del simulador y con las instrucciones de máquina que se utilizan http://www.cs.colby.edu/djskrien/IASSim/  (el simulador está hecho en java por eso puse la etiqueta)

```
; calcular logaritmo base 2 de un número n el cual entregará la parte entera 
;del resultado

loop:   S(x)->Ac+ n ;carga n al acumulador
        Cc->S(x) log ;si el acumulador es >= 0 salta a log
        halt            ; en otro caso termina
        .empty

log:   S(x)->R resm ;copia el número 2 al AR
       S(x)*R->A dos;se multiplica 2*2 
       At->S(x) resm ; se guarda en resm
       S(x)->Ah+ uno ;se aumenta el contador
       At->S(x) cont ;se guarda el contador
       S(x)->Ac+ n ;se carga n al AC
       S(x)->Ah-  uno;se decrementa n en 1
       At->S(x)   n ;se guarda el n 
       Cu->S(x)   loop; vuelve al principio y hace el proceso de nuevo

      n:    .data 4 ;número a calcular logaritmo
      dos:  .data 2 ;base del logaritmo
      uno:  .data 1 ;para ir aumentando el contador
      resm: .data 2 ;aqui se guardara el resultado de la multiplicación
      cont: .data 0 ;se guarda el resultado del logaritmo
```

Este código se prueba en el simulador pero no hace nada porque no está bien.

Comment: Hola @Ravield. ¿En qué lenguaje debes implementar tu simulador y qué es lo que has intentado para implementarlo, cuál es la dificultad que tienes para implementarlo?

Comment: eh oh creo que me exprese mal en el link que deje , hay un simulador de arquitectura von neumann, en ese simulador se usa instrucciones de maquina en el mismo link estan el set de instrucciones que se usa, al final es programar a nivel de maquina, lo que intente fue hacer una serie de multiplicaciones hasta que igualara al numero que estoy aplicando la funcion del log, y me guardara el resultado , no tengo como pasar lo que hice porque extrañamente no me reconoce mi archivo donde tenia lo que habia hecho y aparte no funcionaba

Comment: de hecho lo acabo de lograr hacer funcionar lo colocare en el post

Answer (score 2):

Para implementar el |log2 x| no creo que sea difícil, la idea es simplemente tomar el número x  puede ser en formato `int` (32 bits), luego ir extrayendo desde el bit más significativo y verificar si es `1`. Si no lo es continúa al siguiente bit, y así hasta encontrar un uno o terminar con todos los bits. El resultado de |log2 x| será la cantidad de bits que queden a partir del primer bit en uno.

Hace algún tiempo usé ensamblador para micro-controladores, en esos términos. Podría decir que quedaría algo así en pseudo-código:

```
 1. B = 32
 2. Si B > 0 avanza al paso 3, en caso contrario sigue al paso 7
 3. x << 1  ;corrimiento de bits a la izquierda
 4. acarreo == 0 ? avanza al paso 5  en caso contrario avanza al paso 7
 5. B-- ; resta uno a B
 6. vuelve al paso 2
 7. |Log2 x|= B
 8. Fin
```